# ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant MicropostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

**Update**: This was due to a misspelled file name

correct:
`~/sample_app/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb`

incorrect:
`~/sample_app/app/controllers/microposts_contoller.rb`

---

This is my first contribution here, feedback on improving this or future postings is appreciated :)

Ruby on Rails Tutorial: [Learn Web Development with Rails 4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=4.0)

While working through chapter [10.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts?version=4.0#sec-manipulating_microposts), I got stuck. In the end, a misspelled file name had me chasing ghosts for a few days.

```
$ rspec spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
...FF................

Failures: 

1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller submitting to the create action 
Failure/Error: before { post microposts_path } 
ActionController::RoutingError: 
uninitialized constant MicropostsController 
# ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:93:in `block (6 levels) in ' 

2) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller submitting to the destroy action 
Failure/Error: before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) } 
ActionController::RoutingError: 
uninitialized constant MicropostsController 
# ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:98:in `block (6 levels) in ' 

Finished in 0.92253 seconds 
21 examples, 2 failures 

Failed examples: 

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:94 # Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller submitting to the create action 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:99 # Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller submitting to the destroy action
```

Comment: Update: this was due to a misspelled file name ~/sample_app/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb  (was microposts_contoller.rb)

Comment: Don't comment, answer your own question.

Comment: Agreed you should answer your question so users don't have to read through your entire post and comments before realizing that this has already been solved.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough points - it won't let me answer for another 7 hours. I'll add something to the top.

Comment: In my case the "misspelling" was that I didn't use the plural of the model name.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This was due to a misspelled file name ~/sample_app/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb (was microposts_contoller.rb)

Comment: I appreciate that you put the solution at the very top. I had the exact same issue and was able to fix it quickly. :)

Comment: I'd moved my `controllers` folder up a directory .

Answer (score 6):

This can also happen if you have a nested route mapping a nested directory:

`Started POST "/brokers/properties/5/images/upload" for ...`

`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Brokers::ImagesController):`

```
namespace :brokers do
  resources :properties, only: [] do
    collection do
      post 'upload'
    end
    member do
      resources :images, only: [] do
        collection do
          post 'upload'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You Must place your `images_controller.rb` file with the following structure:

```
-controllers
 |-brokers
   |-images_controller.rb
```

Notice in the directory structure `images_controller.rb` is direct descendant of brokers.

So in order to let Rails find your class don't create a subdirectory `properties` inside `brokers` mapping the route structure, it has to be direct descendent of brokers

Answer (score 3):

Just to help if someone gets stuck with a similar issue:

I misspelled the controller, if you type without the **s in products** it was wrong:

Wrong:

```
get '/my_products', to: 'product#my_products'
```

Right:

```
get '/my_products', to: 'products#my_products'
```

Answer (score 2):

In `routes.rb` I typed `resource` instead of `resources`

Answer (score 0):

in my routes: i had "/"instead of "#" for all the "get", so change that to "#"
  get 'all' => 'storefront#all_items'

get 'categorical' => 'storefront#items_by_category'

get 'branding' => 'storefront#items_by_brand'

that fixed all my errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had incorrectly included the below in my `application_controller.rb`

**Correct:** `include ActionController::MimeResponds`

**Incorrect:** `include ActionController::MimeResponse`

```
# /controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb

module Api
  module V1
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
      include ActionController::MimeResponds
    end
  end
end
```